# angularjs share data config between controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm wondering what could be a good way to share directive
between controller.
I've got ie two directives to use in different controller
with different configuration the first think I thought of
using like:

```
//html
<body data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div data-ui-view></div>
    </div>
</body>

//js
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$upload) {
    /*File upload config*/
    $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
          var file = $files[i];
          $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                url: 'server/upload/url', 
                method: 'POST',
                data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
                file: file,
          }).progress(function(evt) {
            console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            console.log(data);
          });

        }
    };
    /* Datepicker config */
    $scope.showWeeks = true;
    $scope.minDate = new Date();
    $scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.opened = true;
    };
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        'year-format': "'yy'",
        'starting-day': 1
    };
    $scope.format = 'MMM d, yyyy';
})
.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope) {

})
```

doing so I can use all the functions in my children controller
but I don't like very much because of collision problems.
Since you cannot use a service (you can't use $scope in a service) the other alternatives could be make an other directive or put the code in a run block
but it's quite the same using a parent controller so
what do you think about ?

UPDATE

what do you think about this approach ?

```
//outside of angular stauff
function MyTest(){
    this.testScope = function(){
        console.log('It works');
    }
}

//inside a controller
$scope.ns = new MyTest();

//in the view
<p ng-click="ns.testScope()">ppp</p>
```

RIUPDATE
this seems the best option :)

```
MyTest.call($scope);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the method described by this post: [Extending AngularJS Controllers Using the Mixin Pattern](http://digital-drive.com/?p=188)

Instead of copying your methods out of a service, create a base controller that contains those methods, and then call extend on your derived controllers to mix them in.  The example from the post:

```
function AnimalController($scope, vocalization, color, runSpeed) {

    var _this = this;

    // Mixin instance properties.
    this.vocalization = vocalization;
    this.runSpeed = runSpeed;

    // Mixin instance methods.
    this.vocalize = function () {
        console.log(this.vocalization);
    };

    // Mixin scope properties.
    $scope.color = color;

    // Mixin scope methods.
    $scope.run = function(){
        console.log("run speed: " + _this.runSpeed );
    };
}
```

Now we can mixin AnimalController into DogController:

```
function DogController($scope) {

    var _this = this;

    // Mixin Animal functionality into Dog.
    angular.extend(this, new AnimalController($scope, 'BARK BARK!', 'solid black', '35mph'));

    $scope.bark = function () {
        _this.vocalize(); // inherited from mixin.
    }
}
```

And then use DogController in our template:

```
<section ng-controller="DogController">
    <p>Dog</p>

    <!-- Scope property mixin, displays: 'color: solid black' -->
    <p ng-bind-template="color: {{ color }}"></p>

    <!-- Calls an instance method mixin, outputs: 'BARK BARK!' -->
    <button class="btn" ng-click="bark()">Bark Dog</button>

    <!-- Scope method mixin, outputs: 'run speed: 35mph' -->
    <button class="btn" ng-click="run()">Run Dog</button>
</section>
```

The controllers in this example are all in the global space and are included in the markup as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/animal-controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/dog-controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/cat-controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
```

I haven't tested it, but I don't see why the following wouldn't work:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('AnimalController', ['$scope', 'vocalization', 'color', 'runSpeed', function ($scope, vocalization, color, runSpeed) { /* controller code here */}]);

.controller('DogController', ['$scope', '$controller', function($scope, $controller) {
    var _this = this;

    // Mixin Animal functionality into Dog.
    angular.extend(this, $controller('AnimalController', {
         $scope: scope,
         vocalization: 'BARK BARK!', 
         color: 'solid black', 
         runSpeed:'35mph' 
    }));

    $scope.bark = function () {
        _this.vocalize(); // inherited from mixin.
    }
}]);
```

see: [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24controller) for $controller service

Comment: It's just what I'm looking for THANKS :)

Comment: On second thoughts how to do that without using globally-defined controller definition ?

Comment: in the example repo they are globally defined https://github.com/bparvizi/angular-js-controller-mixins.  But there's no reason they have to be -- consider how controllers can be `required` in combination with browserify: http://ethanway.com/angular-and-browserify/ -- but yes, the base controller has to be defined at the point of mixin.

Comment: updated with s version using the $controller service to create the base controller.

Comment: I added just an other reply ^^

Answer (score 3):

What you want is terrible.

You wouldn't want your controllers to know anything about each other, let alone, one having access to the function of the other. You can just use a Service to achieve that. As for using directives, not sure what exactly you want to happen.

As for your second thing, you can as easily do this

```
.service('MyTestService', function(){
    return {
       testScope: function(){
           console.log('It works');
       }
    };
})

.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'MyTestService', function($scope, MyTestService){
   $scope.testScope = MyTestService.testScope;
}])
```

and in your view:

```
<p ng-click="testScope()">ppp</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the point.What about MyTest.call($scope); it seems quite neat as solution ...

Comment: I am quite fidgety about anything that includes globally scoped objects, but yes, it would work, as long as you get $scope to be the correct thingy. You could use that pattern for smoke testing purposes but I wouldn't use it in production code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```
//service
.service('PostUploader',function($upload){
        var that = this;
        var fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader !== null;
        this.notify = null;
        this.success = null;
        this.showAlert = false;
        this.avatar = '';
        this.onFileSelect = function($files) {
            var $file = $files[0];
            var filename = $file.name;
            this.avatar = filename;
            var isImage = /\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/i.test(filename);
            if(!isImage){
                this.showAlert = true;
                return;
            }
            this.showAlert = false;
            if (fileReaderSupported && $file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsDataURL($file);
                fileReader.onload = that.notify;
            }
            $upload.upload({
                url :'/api/post/upload',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'x-ng-file-upload': 'nodeblog'},
        data :null,
        file: $file,
        fileFormDataName: 'avatar'
            })
            .success(that.success)
            .progress(function(evt) {

            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                throw new Error('Upload error status: '+status);
            })

        };
        this.closeAlert = function() {
            this.showAlert = false;
        };
    })    

//controller
 /* Uploader post */
        $scope.dataUrl = null;
        $scope.avatar = PostUploader.avatar;
        $scope.showAlert = PostUploader.showAlert;
        $scope.onFileSelect = PostUploader.onFileSelect;
        $scope.closeAlert = PostUploader.closeAlert;
        PostUploader.notify = function(e){
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.dataUrl = e.target.result;
            });
        };
        PostUploader.success = function(data, status, headers, config) {
           $timeout(function() {
                $scope.post.avatar = data.url;
            });
        }
        $scope.$watch('avatar',function(newVal, oldVal){
            if(newVal) { 
                $scope.avatar = newVal;
            }  
        }); 
        $scope.$watch('showAlert',function(newVal, oldVal){
            $scope.showAlert = newVal;
            $scope.dataUrl = null;
        });
```

I did so because I've to do the same thing in create post and edit post but all in all 
I've got quite the same repeated code ! :)

The only good thing is the code has got less logic.

Answer (score 0):

obvious but brilliant solution (may be)

```
(function(window, angular, undefined) {
                'use strict';
                angular.module('ctrl.parent', [])
                    .run(function ($rootScope) {
                        $rootScope.test = 'My test'   
                        $rootScope.myTest = function(){
                            alert('It works');
                        }
                });
            })(window, angular);
            angular.module('app',['ctrl.parent'])
                .controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope){

            });
```

It's easy and clean and  don't see any drawback(it's not global)

UPDATE

```
'use strict';
                (function(window, angular, undefined) {
                    'use strict';
                    angular.module('ctrl.parent', [])
                        .controller('ParentController',function (scope) {
                            scope.vocalization = '';
                            scope.vocalize = function () {
                                console.log(scope.vocalization);
                            };
                    });
                })(window, angular);
                angular.module('app',['ctrl.parent'])
                    .controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope,$controller){
                    angular.extend($scope, new $controller('ParentController', {scope:$scope}));
$scope.vocalization = 'CIP CIP';
                });
```

just a little neater and it works CIP CIP :)

Comment: The drawback is that you're using $rootScope as your parent controller - what happens if you want more than one parent controller?  It would be cleaner if you define your parent controllers in an angular module, as controllers, and then instantiate it using the $controller service.  I'll update my answer with an example so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I've updated again :) thanks for the point. What do you think ? I just simplify your code

Comment: I've credited you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464810/angular-extend-scope-is-it-safe