# How to watch a variable defined in a service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to watch changes on an json array defined in an angularj service, but when the change occures, the $watch function is not firing. My controller and service code goes as follows ([plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FDL1irj1256CyyBUerQf?p=preview)):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,cityService) {
  //$scope.cities = [];
  $scope.service = cityService;
  cityService.initCities();


  $scope.$watch('service.getCity()', function(newVal) {
    $scope.cities = newVal;
    console.log(newVal)
  });


});

app.service('cityService', function($http) {
  this.cities = [];

  this.initCities = function() {
      $http.get('data.js').success(function(data) {
          this.cities = data;
      });
  };

  this.getCity = function() {
      return this.cities;
  };
});
```

Comment: You can watch a function and not a variable. the function will be evaluaed in each digest. like this  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.foo;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);
});

Comment: Try to take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/21460962/356380

Comment: @Inu. Tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. See my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/8g4Yf2wX7UBwThpy3Bvp?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the callback from get set `this` to `window` object. Keep the reference of the service in `self`.

See this plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/CrgTWRBsg5wi7WOSZiRS?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. Seems I still have to improve on my javascript fundemantal skills. When you come from a C# background it sometimes gets really hard to get used to the way javascript handles scopes.

Comment: Yes the notorious javascript `this`

Answer (score 1):

I changed several things to make it work:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PDMaEvmx7hG1fKvAmR7R?p=preview

- Function watch instead of variable
- In the service, removed the keyword this because this has not the same context inside functions.
- Return functions in service

Seems ok

Comment: Thanks for your help, it does work great, so I voted you up. But it seems that your comment that I have to use a function in the watch is not correct. I modified Chandermanis answer to use a variable instead of a function and it still is working correctly. So, it seems to me that Chandermani's answer is the correct one. http://plnkr.co/edit/8ey5u3NTBSNBDBOVMivn?p=preview