# Communication between controllers Angularjs, service or parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, communication

I am wondering which is best practise, or perhaps in which situation one way is preferred over the other.

The setup is as follows if we use a parent(main) controller:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller Main">
  <div ng-controller="Controller 1"></div>
  <div ng-controller="Controller 2"></div>
</div>
```

So we can communicate here because both controller 1 and 2 have access to Controller Main's scope.

The other way is if we use a service,

```
<div ng-controller="Controller 1"></div>
<div ng-controller="Controller 2"></div>
```

So what I think we're doing is that we inject the service to the controllers.

I've seen both solutions but I don't know which one is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's preferred to use a service. Communicating by using a parent controller breaks encapsulation not to mention it can be pretty buggy if you get someone who doesn't know about the limitations of primitives and scope inheritance etc. Angular's dependency injection works really well and your code will be more flexible in the long run if you do it that way.

Another advantage of a service is code readability. If `Controller 1` references something in `Controller Main` the person reading the code may not know where it came from. With a service you see it injected, you immediately know where to look for it.

Comment: Yes, I started with thinking parent controller is easier, but then it's more modular and easier to read the code if you seperate the different controllers and use a "bridge" between them. I'd also reckon it's easier to extend and maintain the code that way, and perhaps easier to detect bugs. My first solution was actually parent  controller because I've only really comfortable with the scope idea so far, but then I googled a bit and see this new way of introducing services to do the job instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like:

```
'use strict';
                (function(window, angular, undefined) {
                    'use strict';
                    angular.module('ctrl.parent', [])
                        .controller('ParentController',function (scope) {
                            scope.vocalization = '';
                            scope.vocalize = function () {
                                console.log(scope.vocalization);
                            };
                    });
                })(window, angular);
                angular.module('app',['ctrl.parent'])
                    .controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope,$controller){
                    angular.extend($scope, new $controller('ParentController', {scope:$scope}));
$scope.vocalization = 'CIP CIP';
                });
```

take a look [angularjs-share-config-directives-between-controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427027/angularjs-share-config-directives-between-controllers)

it's longish

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with the extend concept but I will look into it.

Comment: This is for sharing config, not necisarily communicating between controllers.