# Best practice for nesting controllers, scopes and models?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've seen (and read) a lot of information on how nested scopes work and I seem to have understood it well and use/abuse it a lot. My question is not about how it's working, it's just a question of how to best use it. Let me give an example.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container" ng-view>
```

The view will load something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="CreateEventCtrl">
...
    <div class="panel-body" ng-include src="'partials/eventinfo.html'">
```

That partial will also have a controller. This all makes great sense to me. I got a MainCtrl that know about your login information, you preferences etc. the CreateEventCtrl will know what is needed to handle creating, editing etc of the event and the specific partial (part of an accordian will need to display some specific information.

I might need to access stuff from one of the parent controllers, which is easy but my problem is; it can be done in so many different ways that I can't seem to figure out what the best way is.

So far I've tried the following implementations.

1. Have MainCtrl create a `$scope.model` that holds basic information and let all other child controllers just extend their own properties onto that model.
2. Have MainCtrl create a `$scope.model` and let child controllers append an extra model like this `$scope.model.createEventModel = { ... }` or just add the model directly on the scope like this `$scope.createEventModel = { ... }`
3. Have MainCtrl create a `$scope.shared` model and let the first level childcontrollers create a `$scope.model` that its next child can either extend, overwrite or add a new `$scope.eventInfoModel` on it, depending on what is best for the current view. All child controllers can opt to extend/overwrite properties on `$scope.shared` as well

It seems there are tons of variations and **I just wonder if there is a best practice on this**. I've tried google it but end up with a ton of posts trying to explain 'the dot', prototypal inheritance and how nested scopes work.

At the moment I'm going with nr.3 but I also know I will probably challenge my own decision at some point and rework it again. I would really want to shortcut all that extra work and learn what other people are doing.

UPDATE: I read everywhere that i should use Services to share data. But I don't get it. The data i want to share might be fetched through a Service but it's a one-way "get/fetch" operation. Also some of the data is user choices that reflect/filter the rest of the data

Comment: I don't know if 'my' approach fits well with your needs but try to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21488757/356380

Comment: Hrm, I only want to share data and not have to worry about what controllers/nesting i have. I don't think it applies so much to my case but thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for best practice this ng-controller="MainCtrl" is quite wrong because of the global issue

Comment: @Whisher can you elaborate on this or help me with a link explaining why?

Comment: I agree with @baba http://stackoverflow.com/a/21428102/356380

Comment: I don't get it. I fail to see the problem and only see extra problems if i were to keep references to viewmodel data in a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I listened to you guys and tried it out. I ended up creating a few services that holds my shared data and then have all controllers needing that information, have it injected.

While i really didn't like this approach to begin with, I find that it makes it clear what controllers will be using the data and what controllers will not. It also kind of helps with separation of concern as i can put all the store/load/modify/cache into the service and not worry about it in the controllers. All i need to do in the controllers is either get the data or put it back.

Comment: There are really only 2 ways to achieve this ... use a service for model persistence or use $rootScope ... however NEVER EVER use $rootScope  this unless there is absolutely no other option because that pollutes the global name space.