# How can I communicate controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some geographic data and I want to show them in a map. I used mapping applications but first time developing map and angularjs. I want to show clicked data in map. I have two controller named Data and Map. how can I communicate them.

Or is there another short way?

[image]

Comment: Use event broadcasting/emitting, or use a service

Comment: Use a service/factory. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/) about it.

Comment: Googling looking for angular parent controller mixin take also a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427027/angularjs-share-data-config-between-controllers

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 possibilities:

1. Create a service/factory on the same module. Inject it into both controllers. Add it to $scope

   ```
   $scope.sharedService = myInjectedservice;
   ```

   of both controllers. Now any changes you make to the properties exposed by the service will be visible to both controllers.
2. Depending on how you designed the controller hierarchy, either $scope.$emit (event travels up to parent scopes) or $scope.$broadcast (event travels down) an event and add a listener for that event to the receiving controller

   ```
   $scope.$on("eventName", function(event, params){
        //event handler code goes here
   });
   ```