# Why can't I inject a controller into a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

My application has a multi-tab order wizard. It has one Controller called OrderController. I decided I wanted to have one controller per tab, and for OrderController to manage all the tabs and navigation.

OrderController contained a static array of tab information (title, partial, etc). I decided that each tab should supply its own information to OrderController instead.

I made a 'tab 1' controller and a function that would return the tab information to OrderController. I injected 'tab 1' into OrderController but this failed with a 'no provider' error. I did some googling and found various ways a controller could talk to a controller. None involved a direct injection like I was attempting.

I tried a tab-specific Factory instead. (Maybe not a bad idea anyway since the information being provided is static.) This worked fine.

Sorry for the long-winded post.

But why can't I inject one controller into another, technically? Angularjs was having no part of it. Why is this a bad idea, logically?

Comment: You could use `$controller` service to create new instances of those tab controllers, but you also can't get the existings instances this way.

Comment: Try like .controller('PostCreateCtrl', function ($scope) {
   angular.extend($scope, new $controller('PostParentCtrl', {
            $scope:$scope
})); take alook at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427027/angularjs-share-data-config-between-controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Controllers don't really exist that way. They're the OO equivalent of a "template" for a set of behaviors and variables. They aren't created until they're actually *used* somewhere. The injector can only give you things that exist globally, and controllers aren't global.

A Factory (or if you don't need special creation behavior, a Service is the same thing but a little shorter to write) is exactly this pattern. It is a global singleton object (exactly one instance exists at all times) so the injector can find it and give it to you.

It's really just because there's no pattern for Angular to inject "Controller 4". Controllers can have 0..N instances at any time. How would it know which one you want? Just because you aren't *planning* to have more than one of this component doesn't mean you couldn't or others wouldn't. It's just not the injector's job.

Comment: Pretty much this. Since there is not just one instance of a given controller injecting it ANYWHERE is pointless so you would just create a new instance of it that is not used anywhere in the DOM.